# Why soft input keyboard destroys my display?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

Here is my normal display:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KluX.jpg

Here is my display when the first field 'Nom d'utilisateur' has the focus:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c5TS.jpg

My button lost its padding.

I am using
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

And here is my button shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
    <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="@color/loginButtonBorderLight" />
    <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: I need to let the button visible during the user input

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your menifest file : android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"

Comment: Will the button always be visible during input ?

Comment: Try to put your button inside of a ScrollView and then set isScrollable = false.